# Unable to display Level.FINE logs

Tags: java, logging

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLI.class.getName());
    private static final Handler CONSOLE_HANDLER = new ConsoleHandler();

    static {
        CONSOLE_HANDLER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        LOGGER.addHandler(CONSOLE_HANDLER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.fine("test");
    }
```

What am I missing here, I've already set the handler's log level to ALL but still not printing "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CLI.class.getName()` logger inherits the log level of the root logger.  Lower the log level of the root logger or just [lower the level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setLevel-java.util.logging.Level-) of the `CLI.class.getName()` logger.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLI.class.getName());
private static final Handler CONSOLE_HANDLER = new ConsoleHandler();

static {
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    LOGGER.setUseParentHandlers(false); //Don't report to the root console handler.

    CONSOLE_HANDLER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    LOGGER.addHandler(CONSOLE_HANDLER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOGGER.fine("test");
}
```